# how to install wine x86 and box86 on raspi4 in docker to run GUI applications?

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, wine

I've been looking all over the internet to find out how to do this but seem to only get either an example of box86 and winex86 already pre-installed and running apps on them or just winex86 without box86. So what I'm trying to do is get apps like Minecraft/Multimc to run in a docker container in GUI mode through wine and box86. Yes, I know that Minecraft(old) is a java program and can be run on arm Linux but I usually use Multimc which to my knowledge is not, and while yes you "can" install it doesn't work because the 32-bit support is non-existant. I also think that it would be nice to have an easy to use docker container that can run windows x86 on docker hub. Besides those ambitions, I wonder if this would be possible and or even worth it.

If anyone knows how to do this please respond/answer.

Comment: Java minecraft is a hungry application. My guess is that it's unlikely you get good enough performance to run this.

Comment: Yeah but I don't know why I stressed so much about Minecraft but that was more of an example of a program I would like to run.

Comment: I am not saying functionally run it but the ability to run it.